# jQuery draggable position bug

Tags: jquery, draggable

guys I have a problem with jQuery :(

html:

```
<div id = 'container'>
<div class = 'draggable' style="margin: auto; left: 0; right: 0; top: 50%; bottom: 50%; background: red;"></div>
```

js:

```
$('.draggable').draggable();
```

look http://jsfiddle.net/EZweB/236/

move does not work properly and do not know how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

Easy does it: remove the

`position:absolute;`

from the CSS
Check: http://jsfiddle.net/ryc461h1/
Cheers!

change javascript:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).css('position','relative');
    },
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).removeAttr("style");
    }
    });
```

check: http://jsfiddle.net/bevrk06p/

Comment: unfortunately does not work, look http://jsfiddle.net/EZweB/237/
if you remove the "position: absolute" blocks will have bad positions

Comment: again you did not remove 'position:absolute;' from .draggable in CSS. check http://jsfiddle.net/ge9jvzs6/

Comment: whaat do these images mean?

Comment: in this picture are shown'll live what I see when I remove "position: absolute"